# change height of a thead in a table

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to change the height of a `thead` in a `table`? I have tried

```
$('thead').height('2px');
```

but to no avail, the height does not change.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve?  You might be able to get what you want by setting a border on the table or padding on the first row in the body (since it's hard to imagine you have content in a 2px high block).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is probably browser dependent.  Some browsers may treat the thead element as a container without any height of it's own. Try setting a height on the TH elements themselves, using Javascript or CSS.  Note that to achieve something less than the height of a line, you'd also have to set the line height as a table element will resize to fit it's content.

```
$('thead th').css({ height: '2px', line-height: '2px' });
```

or

```
 <style>
    .header th {
       height: 2px;
       line-height: 2px;
    }
 <style>

 <table>
    <thead class="header">
        <th>Foo</th>
        ...
    </thead>
    ...
 </table>
```

As @Marco notes in his example, you can probably also force the THEAD to be treated as a block level element and set it's height directly.  Depending on what you're trying to accomplish and what is in the row contained in the THEAD, this may or may not do what you want.  More information on what you're trying to achieve may help us find the appropriate solution for you.

Comment: Dosent seem to work, see http://jsfiddle.net/KWbxL/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/KWbxL/3/ - it must have something to do with how tables are treated, since it always tries to make the content visible... This thread peaked my interest :)

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen - I don't think you can size a table element smaller than it's content.  I'm assuming that for a 2px row, you'd only have whitespace in it and set the line height as well.  Seems like it would be more appropriate to use padding on the first body row, but I'm waiting on an update from the OP to clarify. http://jsfiddle.net/KWbxL/4/

Comment: I originally drew up my example based on yours which *increased* the height of the header.  Of course if you're making it smaller you have to take account of the resizing behavior and make sure that the content doesn't force it larger than you want.  Yet another good reason not to use tables inappropriately for layout!

Comment: Agree agree.. Great spotted it was line-height being the problem. Don't think we disagree its a bad idea, to use elements for simple styling, nor doing CSS work with JS. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/KWbxL/1/

Its displaying as a table, which cant have a LESS height, than its content.
So if you need 2px height, you need to display:block and have overflow:hidden for hiding the content (which wont fit in the 2px).

And why not use CSS, instead of using JS to do your styling :)

Comment: Doesn't work in Safari.  I had to set a height on the TH elements for it to work in Safari.

Comment: Yes.  Works in Safari now that you've forced it to treat the THEAD as a block level element.

Comment: The whole purpose of using `thead` will be lost if we change the display property. If that is the case, we should use `div` instead of `thead`.